# play framework mandatory item

Tags: validation, playframework

Is it possible to automatically put a * before a required field label? In this example firstname is required (@Required in the model) and therefore a * should be shown after firstname in the label.

Sample code:

```
#{field 'user.firstname'}
    <div class="field">
        <label for="${field.id}">&{'customer.firstname'}${field.}</label>
        <input id="${field.id}" size="30" type="text" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}" class="${field.errorClass}" />
        <span class="error">${field.error}</span>
    </div>
#{/field}
```

Comment: what does your #{field} macro do?

Comment: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/tags

Comment: So as Pere said, you should change the #field tag to analyze the @Required annotation potentially set on this field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit the #{field /} tag to recognize the field annotations and draw the * automatically.

Or you could extend the [jqvalidate](http://www.playframework.org/modules/jqvalidate) module to add that via Javascript.

Comment: #{field/} is a tag from the framework, you would need to copy the source of the tag and put it in your app. I think modifying the jqvalidate module is easier. Just add an empty span in your code and in the module fill the span with * if the @required annotation exists